# An attempt at an epsilon-delta proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

I've been trying to construct a proof of the fundamental theorem of calculus (FTC) using an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ limit proof, but I've come a bit unstuck half-way through. Here's my attempt so far.

Let $f$ be continuous in the interval $[a,b]$ and define a function $F : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ that is differentiable on $(a,b)$, such that $$F(x)=\int_{a}^{x}f(t)dt$$

As $f$ is continuous $\forall t\in[a,b]$ and, in particular, at $t=x$, we know that for any $\varepsilon >0$  $\exists\delta >0$ such that , $$0<\vert t-x\vert <\delta\quad\Rightarrow\quad\big\vert f(t)-f(x)\big\vert <\varepsilon$$ i.e. the limit $$\lim_{t\rightarrow x}f(t)=f(x)$$ exists (where $x\in[a,b]$).

Given this we consider an interval $[x,x+h]\subset[a,b]$ where $h>0$ is some real number, and from this notice that $$x\leq t\leq (x+h)\Rightarrow 0\leq t-x\leq h$$ and this motivates us to assume that there is a $\delta >0$ such that $0<h<\delta$. We can then use that, whenever $t\in[x,x+h]$ we have that $\vert t-x\vert<\delta$ and so $$\big\vert f(t)-f(x)\big\vert <\varepsilon\quad\Rightarrow\quad f(x)-\varepsilon <f(t)<f(x)+\varepsilon$$ Thus, upon integrating over the interval $[x,x+h]$ we obtain $$\int_{x}^{x+h}[f(x)-\varepsilon]dt <\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t)dt<\int_{x}^{x+h}[f(x)+\varepsilon]dt\\ \\ \Rightarrow [f(x)-\varepsilon]h<\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t)dt<[f(x)+\varepsilon]h\;\;\;\\ \\ \Rightarrow f(x)-\varepsilon<\frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t)dt<f(x)+\varepsilon\qquad\\ \\ \Rightarrow\Bigg\vert\frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t)dt -f(x)\Bigg\vert<\varepsilon\qquad\qquad\qquad\;$$ which implies that the limit $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t)dt =f(x)$$ Furthermore, as $$F(x+h)-F(x)=\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t)dt$$ Then $$\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{1}{h}\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t)dt=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0^{+}}\frac{F(x+h)-F(x)}{h}=f(x)$$

I'm unsure if this first part is completely correct and also how to consider the case in which $h<0$?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: "...we know that $\exists \delta >0$ such that for any $\varepsilon >0$..." You mean the contrary logical order: for any $\varepsilon$ there is a $\delta$. That said, can you show that $\lim_\limits{h\to 0^+} (F(x+h)-F(x))/h=\lim_\limits{h\to 0^-}(F(x+h)-F(x))/h=f(x)$ implies $\lim_\limits{h\to 0}(F(x+h)-F(x))/h=f(x)$?

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, have edited it to the correct order now.
How do I show that the same limit exists for $h<0$ though (such that the two limits are equal and the derivative of $F$ at $x$ exists)?

Comment: You could have used uniform continuity and how did you get rid of the integrals here: $\Rightarrow [f(x)-\varepsilon]h<\int_{x}^{x+h}f(t)dt<[f(x)+\varepsilon]h$

Comment: What do you mean by uniform continuity?
$f(x)$ and $\varepsilon$ are independent of $t$ and so can be taken outside the integral, leaving $\int_{x}^{x+h}dt=h$.

Comment: @graydad if $f$ is continuous on $[a,b]$, then it is uniformly continuous.

Comment: @Perpetuallearner I am not an expert but it doesn't seem rigorous (if not it is wrong).

Comment: What is incorrect/non-rigorous about it?

Comment: @Perpetuallearner We are not dealing with multi variable calculus right? You can't treat $dt$ and $dx$ are different things. So you can define $g(t)=f(t)-\varepsilon$ which is not constant along $dt$. But as I said it is my opinion.

Comment: As far as I understand it $f(x)$ is the value of the function $f$ evaluated at the point $x\in[a,b]$ and as such it is constant, whereas $t$ is a dummy variable of integration, but I may be wrong?! The notation is a bit misleading I admit, but $f(x)$ is the value of $f$ evaluated at a fixed (but arbitrary) point in the interval $[a,b]$ whereas $f(t)$ is treated as a function (where $f$ is a function of $t$). In other words $x$ is taken to be a particular value of $t$ within the interval $[a,b]$.